# Add the previous element for each element in a list in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, tail-recursion

I want to do something like this:

If I have the following list:

```
[1;2;3;4;5]
```

I want to obtain this one:

```
[1;3;6;10;15] -> result of doing [0+1=1; 1+2=3; 3+3=6; 6+4=10; 10+5=15]
```

I have the following code, but it not tail recursive

```
let sumsum l = List.fold_right (fun x t -> x::List.map ((+) x) t) l [];;
```

Im stucked doing it tail recursive, could someone help me?

Its possible to do it without using List.fold_right, List.fold_left and List.map?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for `scan` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let sumsum l =
  let rec aux a' acc = function
    | []    -> List.rev acc
    | a::tl -> let b=a+a' in aux b (b::acc) tl
  in
  aux 0 [] l
;;
```

test

```
# sumsum [1;2;3;4;5];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 6; 10; 15]
```